# Best practices for showing selection states in dropdowns

Tags: interaction-design, dropdown, selection, states, redundancy

I'm designing a CRM-style interface for medical assistants, and I'm wondering if putting a check next to the selected state in a dropdown is redundant if that state is already showing on main screen? (see screenshot).

Would love to hear your thoughts. Thanks!

[image: Dropdown with selection state]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with it. I would highlight it in blue instead of the check mark (but it is a personal preference). I do not think you should be concerned about redundancy as highlighting it on the **drop-down** **is not** redundant to highlighting it on the **page**. Each one serves a **different** goal!

Comment: thanks @mo'ath, thats an excellent point!